# OpenGL overwrites Windows' buttons

Tags: c++, opengl

I have following code:

```
void DrawGLScene(unsigned char *drawing_bytes, HDC hdc, int xWidth, int yWidth) {
    if ((!xWidth) || (!yWidth)) return;

    BOOL returnVal = wglMakeCurrent(hdc, hrc);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture); 

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, xWidth, yWidth, 0, GL_BGR_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, drawing_bytes); 
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);

    glViewport(0,0,xWidth,yWidth);                      // Reset The Current Viewport

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);                        // Select The Projection Matrix
    glLoadIdentity();                                   // Reset The Projection Matrix

    // Calculate The Aspect Ratio Of The Window
    gluPerspective(25.0f,1.0f,0.1f,100.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);                         // Select The Modelview Matrix
    glLoadIdentity();                                   // Reset The Modelview Matrix

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);                            // Enable Texture Mapping
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);                            // Enable Smooth Shading
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);                           // Enables Depth Testing
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);                             // The Type Of Depth Testing To Do
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);  // Really Nice Perspective Calculations

    glLoadIdentity();                                   // Reset The View
    glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,-5.0f);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        // Front Face
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  0.5f);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  0.5f);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f,  0.5f);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  0.5f);
    glEnd();

    glSwapBuffers(hdc);
}
```

This code overwrites my buttons created earlier via

```
hInstallButton = CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), "",
                     WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_AUTOCHECKBOX,
                     137, 70, 13, 13,        
                     hWnd, (HMENU) 1, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
```

The issue is the glSwapBuffers(), which hides the buttons for good. 
This is generated by the PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR

```
static  PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd=              // pfd Tells Windows How We Want Things To Be
    {
        sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),              // Size Of This Pixel Format Descriptor
        1,                                          // Version Number
        PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |                        // Format Must Support Window
        PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL |                        // Format Must Support OpenGL
        0,                          // Must Support Double Buffering
        PFD_TYPE_RGBA,                              // Request An RGBA Format
        24,                                     // Select Our Color Depth
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                           // Color Bits Ignored
        0,                                          // No Alpha Buffer
        0,                                          // Shift Bit Ignored
        0,                                          // No Accumulation Buffer
        0, 0, 0, 0,                                 // Accumulation Bits Ignored
        16,                                         // 16Bit Z-Buffer (Depth Buffer)  
        0,                                          // No Stencil Buffer
        0,                                          // No Auxiliary Buffer
        PFD_MAIN_PLANE,                             // Main Drawing Layer
        0,                                          // Reserved
        0, 0, 0                                     // Layer Masks Ignored
    };
```

How can I force a single buffer, or something to write the buttons to both buffers? I am at a good loss here, and don't know how to do it properly (except maybe recreate the buttons with each WM_PAINT call)?

Edit:
Tried with subwindow (see code), but it creates a second window, instead of embedding into the first window.

```
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd;

    hInst = hInstance; // Instanzenhandle in der globalen Variablen speichern
    DWORD       dwExStyle;              // Window Extended Style
    DWORD       dwStyle;                // Window Style

    hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if (!hWnd) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    dwExStyle=WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE | CS_OWNDC;            // Window Extended Style
    dwStyle=WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN;                         // Windows Style
    WNDCLASS wndClass;
    wndClass.style = CS_OWNDC | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndClass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wndClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndClass.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(BLACK_BRUSH);
    wndClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndClass.lpszClassName = "Test Window";
    RegisterClass(&wndClass);

    hWndOpenGL = CreateWindowEx(    dwExStyle,                          // Extended Style For The Window
        "Test Window",                          // Class Name
        "Testy test",                               // Window Title
        dwStyle,                            // Required Window Style
        0, 0,                           // Window Position
        800,    
        600,    
        hWnd,                               // Parent Window
        NULL,                               // No Menu
        hInstance,                          // Instance
        NULL);

    //CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    //CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT-500, 0, hWnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    static  PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd=              // pfd Tells Windows How We Want Things To Be
    {
        sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),              // Size Of This Pixel Format Descriptor
        1,                                          // Version Number
        PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |                        // Format Must Support Window
        PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL |                        // Format Must Support OpenGL
        0,                                          // Must Support Double Buffering
        PFD_TYPE_RGBA,                              // Request An RGBA Format
        24,                                     // Select Our Color Depth
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                           // Color Bits Ignored
        0,                                          // No Alpha Buffer
        0,                                          // Shift Bit Ignored
        0,                                          // No Accumulation Buffer
        0, 0, 0, 0,                                 // Accumulation Bits Ignored
        16,                                         // 16Bit Z-Buffer (Depth Buffer)  
        0,                                          // No Stencil Buffer
        0,                                          // No Auxiliary Buffer
        PFD_MAIN_PLANE,                             // Main Drawing Layer
        0,                                          // Reserved
        0, 0, 0                                     // Layer Masks Ignored
    };

    hdcOpenGL=GetDC(hWndOpenGL);

    GLuint      PixelFormat;            // Holds The Results After Searching For A Match
    PixelFormat=ChoosePixelFormat(hdcOpenGL,&pfd);

    SetPixelFormat(hdcOpenGL,PixelFormat,&pfd);

    hrc=wglCreateContext(hdcOpenGL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    ShowWindow(hWndOpenGL, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWndOpenGL);

    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that you created the buttons as childs of the OpenGL window. If you did this, well, then you actually did something, that's explicitly mentioned in the WGL and Win32 API documentation to break things .

The fix is simple: The OpenGL window should be a sibling to the buttons and have its very own DC: Create a own subwindow for OpenGL operations with the `CS_OWNDC` window class flag set and the `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN` window styles being set. Both the OpenGL subwindow and the buttons are created with the desired container window as parent.

That way the buttons will not get clobbered by OpenGL operations, even with a double buffered pixelformat.

Comment: Can you share the CreateWindowEx() function for that? I have tested it, but cannot get it to work. I have edited my question to show the code I have been using. It shows two windows now, but I want it to be in one window only.

Comment: @SinisterMJ: For the OpenGL subwindow use `dwExStyle=0`, the class should specify no icon and no background brush (otherwise your OpenGL drawing will flicker); since the OpenGL subwindow is not a toplevel window it does not require a title; for clarity reasons just use the `wndClass.lpszClassName` in CreateWindowEx; make sure the class name is different from the parent window's class. Your container window must have a `WM_SIZE` event handler, that resizes the OpenGL subwindow accordingly. dwStyle needs the `WS_CHILD` style being set.

Comment: Okay, I have done that, but its still a second window opening. I am close to just living with two windows being open, but ideal would really be one big window, with two areas (one button area, one OpenGL area)